# Getting sum() on a different distinct row MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, sum, distinct

I was looking on different questions on this issue, but couldn't find an answer for my problem.

This is my query:

```
SELECT SUM( lead_value ) AS lead_value_sum, count( DISTINCT phone ) AS SUM, referer
FROM leads t1
INNER JOIN leads_people_details t2 ON t1.lead_id = t2.lead_id
INNER JOIN user_to_leads t3 ON t1.lead_id = t3.lead_id
WHERE lead_date
BETWEEN 20100716000000
AND 20100716235959
AND t1.site_id =8
GROUP BY t1.referer
```

I am trying to sum up the lead_value **only** of unique phone numbers. The count (Distinct phone) actually works and gives me the number of unique phones for each referer, but I can't seem to understand how should I SUM the lead_value for unique phone numbers at each referer.

Would appreciate any help you can give me,
Eden

**Edit:** Table Structures

```
CREATE TABLE user_to_leads
 (
user_idINT(10) NOT NULL,
lead_idINT(10) NOT NULL,
site_idINT(10) NOT NULL,
lead_value INT(10) NOT NULL
 )

CREATE TABLE leads
 (
lead_id INT(100) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
site_id INT(10) NOT NULL ,
lead_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
vaild_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
referer VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
KEYWORD VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
upsaleINT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
vaild INT(2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (lead_id),
KEY lead_date (lead_date)
 )


CREATE TABLE leads_people_details
 (
lead_id INT(100) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
fullnameVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
phone VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL ,
email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
homeVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
browser VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
browser_version VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
resolutionVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
IPVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
statusVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
COMMENT text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (lead_id)
 )
```

Comment: It's unclear from the sql what you want to achieve:

is it let's say you have 3 phone numbers say like this:

613-555-1001   
613-555-1001   
613-555-1001   
613-555-1002
613-555-1002
613-555-1003

then 

you want to get 613-555-1001 lead_value_sum == 3; 613-555-1002 lead_value_sum == 2, 613-555-1001 lead_value_sum == 1 ?

Comment: Do you have different `lead_value` numbers for a particular `referer, phone` combination or will it always be the same? If different which one do you want to add for the SUM? And what RDBMS are you using (it might not make any difference but best to know). Also would help if you told us the structure of your tables.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your fast answers.

Elf King - 
SUM = gives me the number of unique phone numbers for each referrer.
lead_value_sum = gives me the SUM of all lead_value attached to each unique phone number  for each referrer. Right now it counts all of the lead_value for each referrer, even if there are 2 rows with the same phone number.

Martin Smith:
For a particular referer,phone, the lead_value will always be the same, so I don't mind just picking the first lead_value available.

RDBMS  - I am using PHPMYADMIN, is that what you meant?

Comment: In fact the whole table definitions would be best.

Comment: Hey Martin - is there a a preferred way I should show you the structure of the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say

> For a particular referer,phone, the
>   lead_value will always be the same

Based on the limited information you have given I think this should return the right answer. If you update your question with the requested information it will probably be possible to improve upon it though.

```
SELECT SUM(lead_value ) AS lead_value_sum, count(phone ) AS phone_count, referer
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT lead_value, phone, referer
FROM leads t1
INNER JOIN leads_people_details t2 ON t1.lead_id = t2.lead_id
INNER JOIN user_to_leads t3 ON t1.lead_id = t3.lead_id
WHERE lead_date
BETWEEN 20100716000000
AND 20100716235959
AND t1.site_id =8
) derived
GROUP BY referer
```

**Upated after table structure posted**

I don't really understand why have both `leads_people_details` and `leads` got a primary key and auto_increment column of `lead_id` that you are joining on? That would imply a 1-1 relationship between leads and leads_people_details? If so one of them probably shouldn't be an auto_increment to avoid the possibility of the ids getting out of synch without you realising.

Also there is no Primary Key on the user_to_leads table. Should there one on `user_id`, `lead_id`, `site_id`? Additionally you are not currently filtering by siteid on *that* table. Is that intentional? If not if you do that does that stop the duplicate records from coming back? If it doesn't then can you describe the significance of `user_id` in that table? You earlier said that For a particular `referer,phone`, the `lead_value` will always be the same can it differ by `user_id`? If so which should be used? If not why is `user_id` in that table?

A provisional query that might be closer is here but there are still the unresolved queries above.

```
SELECT SUM(lead_value ) AS lead_value_sum, count(phone ) AS phone_count, referer
FROM leads t1
INNER JOIN leads_people_details t2 ON t1.lead_id = t2.lead_id
INNER JOIN user_to_leads t3 ON t1.lead_id = t3.lead_id  
               and t1.site_id = t3.site_id
WHERE lead_date
BETWEEN 20100716000000
AND 20100716235959
AND t1.site_id =8
```

Comment: Hey Martin Smith, it seems your solution worked well, at least for this specific stats, I will be checking it for more of course.

Can you please explain me what exactly have you done? Is the "FROM" choosing from a table you are creating right inside the query?
And what is derived all about? :)

Thanks so much for your help,
Eden

Comment: @Eden - Really I just need to know what columns go in each of the tables. At the moment it brings back duplicates then gets rid of them with distinct. I'm hoping that I should be able to get rid of this step and make things more efficient. The derived bit refers to a derived table. It is like an inline view.

Comment: You are right - leads_people_details doesn't have to be auto_increment, every time I insert the people details I use the lead_id that was just added to leads, so they are always the same. 

user_to_leads - I have to have a primary key? Which one should I use then?

each lead_id is attached to a user_id (sometimes even more than 1), telling me to which user to lead is "attached" to. each user_id has a different lead_value, so for your next questions - same referrer and phone will be always the same lead_value, but it WILL differ by different user_ids, which each gives a different lead_value.

Comment: continuing my message :
I don't understand how your new query solves 2 rows for same site (example - 8), which in the people_details table it has the same phone - where does it filter the double phone if it's on the same site?

Comment: @Eden - But you're not joining `userid` onto anything. Which means in that case `referer,phone` *will* have different `lead_value` s in the query in the case you have just described. Additionally can the value of `site_id` in `user_to_leads` ever be any different than the corresponding `site_id` in `leads`?

Comment: Hey Martin,
The site_id attached to each row in leads (linked via lead_id) is always the same site_id used to link user_to_leads to leads, also via lead_id.

Can you please explain me how the new last query you wrote solves the problem of rows having the same phone, needing to counting only one lead_sum and only summing one lead_value and not all together?

Comment: @Edeb - It probably doesn't. The key phrase was "A provisional query that might be closer". I'm not really clear about your data model so I guess just use the first one if it works for you!

Comment: Hey Martin, didn't the tables structure I attached before is enough to learn the data model? The first soultion seems to work, but I think it slows down the query too much because it uses a sub query, I hoped I can find a more elegant way to solve this one..